# C++ 'else' in loops

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement

In C++, I have run into a problem when I am doing loops. I just know there is an obvious solution I am just overlooking in my work. Here is an example for reference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

string loop();

int main()
{
    string answer;
    do
    {
        cout << "Do you wish to be asked this question again?: ";
        cin >> answer;
        if (answer == "no" || answer == "No" || answer == "NO")
            cout << "As you wish";
        else if (answer == "yes" || answer == "Yes" || answer == "YES")
            cout << "";
        else
        {
            cout << "You didn't answer yes or no\n";
            loop();
        }
    }while (answer == "yes" || answer == "Yes" || answer == "YES");
    return 0;
}

string loop()
{
        string answer;
        cout << "Do you wish to be asked this question again?: ";
        cin >> answer;
        if (answer == "no" || answer == "No" || answer == "NO")
            cout << "As you wish";
        else if (answer == "yes" || answer == "Yes" || answer == "YES")
            cout << "";
        else
        {
            cout << "You didn't answer yes or no\n";
            loop();
        }
        return answer;
}
```

When I am doing an If-else in a loop, I run into a problem when it comes to the `else` section. I cant seem to figure out how to display something that tells the user there is an error, and then re-run the same sequence. For example, in the program I included, when the user enters something other than yes or no, I am not sure how to show an error statement and then loop it back to the top so it asks the question again.

Comment: Btw, you could first convert the answer string to lower case so that you wouldn't need to test all possible combinations, just "yes" or "no".

Comment: @juzzlin: nice remark. How do you convert a string to lowercase in C++?

Comment: Recursion isn't the appropriate approach to solve this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a while loop.

```
string answer;

while ( (answer != "yes") && (answer != "no") ) {
    cout << "Do you wish to be asked this question again?: ";
    cin >> answer;

    if (answer == "no" || answer == "No" || answer == "NO") {
        cout << "As you wish";
        break;
    }

    if (answer == "yes" || answer == "Yes" || answer == "YES") {
        cout << "";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to break if he says yes? shouldn't it just continue?

Comment: While this definitely works well for this example, what if I have multiple conditions? I am trying to avoid entering several "variable != 'answer'" lines in the while conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the loop; the problem is you've got your logic all tangled up. The solution isn't a way to fix the loop, the solution is a way to straighten up your logic.

A simple trick which is a lot more useful than it appears is to completely separate the loop from the thing you do in the loop:

```
// This function does something, then returns a boolean value
// to indicate whether or not you should continue looping.
bool do_something();

int main()
{
    bool continue_looping = true;
    while (continue_looping) {
        continue_looping = do_something();
    }
}
```

Now, you implement `do_something()` in a way that doesn't have to worry about actually *doing* the looping; it's only responsibility in that regard is to return a value that indicates whether looping should continue.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a single do-while loop...

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string ans{""};
    transform(ans.begin(), ans.end(), ans.begin(), ::tolower); // convert string to lower case

    do {
        cout << "Do you wish to be asked this question again? ";
        cin >> ans;
        if (ans == "no") {
            cout << "As you wish.";
        } else
        if (ans == "yes") {
            cout << "";
        }
        else {
            cout << "You didn't answer yes or no." << endl;         
        }

    } while (ans != "yes" && ans != "no");  

    return 0;
}
```

Note, the **transform** algorithm converts the string into lower case to avoid variations in the spelling of *yes* and *no*.